# Can I save code within <script>...</script> in a different file and include it?

Tags: javascript

Really basic javascript question:

Can I save code within `<script>...</script>` in a different file and include it?

Will it work exactly the same?

Can I include it in the exact same place as the `<script>...</script>`?

Comment: yes, create a .js file and include it `<script src="pathtofile"></script>`

Comment: this question proves a severe lack of investigation, googling "include javascript file in html" gives plenty results, not to mention it's already been asked and answered on this site too...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Put a `src` attribute (where the value is the URL of the script) on the `<script>` element (then leave the element content empty).

Answer (score 0):

Save your Code in a file, name it xyz.js and include it:

```
<script src="path/xyz.js"></script>
```